# Ajax Cross domain request to non-controlled domain

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, cors

I have been seeing lot of questions and answers here, but something really not answered my questions

1. How do I make a cross domain request to a http://otherdomain.com?login.php?username="test"&pass="pass"

I would like to state that, this domain is not controlled by us and it will return normal HTTP response if you actually make a HTTP POST request to the above URL.

So based on the HTTP Response [HTML], I would like to evaluate successful or failure login.

Since it's an internal application, if it's not possible in normal scenario, we can configure internal system browsers to achieve the same [last option].

Can anyone post a link to tutorial/working example?

Note: I don't  have control over otherdomain application. It doesn't return a JSON formatted data. The request must be originated from Clients browser, not allowed any proxy due to application dependance on IP address.

Comment: You can run chrome with a certain flag that disables security restrictions.  Only do it if you're not going to use the browsers for anything else.  Chrome/FF extensions are another method.

Comment: You can let your proxy forward the client IP.

Comment: @mplungjan, when the request goes to otherdomain, the request should look like generated from the user IP. is it possible? If so, please post the solution

Comment: Depends on your server - http://serverfault.com/questions/331079/haproxy-and-forwarding-client-ip-address-to-servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy). None of them will meet your requirements.

Preventing Mallory's site from using Alice's site with Bob's credentials (such as his IP address) is the *point* of the Same Origin Policy. There is no way around this for a web application.

> Since it's an internal application

If it is an internal application, then you could look at using a browser extension to access the data. They have less restrictive security policies as they have to be explicitly installed.